# C++ Map inserts pairs with duplicated key

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to use map with MAC as key. I wrote user defined class for MAC and overload operator< to use in map.

```
class Mac {
public:
    uint8_t addr[6];

    std::string to_string() const {
        char mac_to_string[18];

        sprintf(mac_to_string, "%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", addr[0], addr[1], addr[2], addr[3], addr[4], addr[5]);

        return std::string(mac_to_string);
    }

    Mac &operator=(const Mac &rhs) {
        memcpy(addr, rhs.addr, sizeof(Mac));

        return *this;
    }

    Mac &operator=(uint8_t rhs[6]) {
        memcpy(addr, rhs, sizeof(Mac));

        return *this;
    }

    bool operator<(const Mac &rhs) const {
        return memcmp(addr, rhs.addr, sizeof(Mac)) != 0;
    }
};
```

I have some logic that add data into map. Is true that insert function is called even MAC address is already in map. But map has to not insert if key exists but it isn't. The pair with same key has same data. How can I solve it?

```
class MacPair {
public:
    Mac src_mac;
    Mac dst_mac;

    MacPair() {

    }

    MacPair(uint8_t src_mac[6], uint8_t dst_mac[6]) {
        this->src_mac = src_mac;
        this->dst_mac = dst_mac;
    }

    MacPair &operator=(const MacPair &rhs) {
        src_mac = rhs.src_mac;
        dst_mac = rhs.dst_mac;

        return *this;
    }

    bool operator<(const MacPair &rhs) const {
        return src_mac < rhs.src_mac || dst_mac < rhs.dst_mac;
    }
};

...
if (obj->mac_conversations.find(mac_pair) != obj->mac_conversations.end()) {
    mac_exists = true;
}
else if (obj->mac_conversations.find(rev_mac_pair) != obj->mac_conversations.end()) {
    mac_exists = true;
    mac_is_reverse = true;
}

if (!mac_exists) {
    obj->mac_conversations.insert(make_pair(mac_pair, PacketInfo()));
    obj->mac_endpoints.insert(make_pair(mac_pair.src_mac, PacketInfo()));
    obj->mac_endpoints.insert(make_pair(mac_pair.dst_mac, PacketInfo()));
    mac_exists = true;
}
...
```

[image]

Comment: Your `operator <()` is incorrectly defined. `!= 0` does not mean `<`, it is also true for `>`.

Comment: You do not need to implement an overloaded assignment operator or copy constructor in your `Mac` class or your `MacPair` class.  You really only need to implement these methods when the compiler supplied implementation won't suffice (e.g. when you need to clone something dynamically allocated instead of letting the pointer just copy over).  In other words, without an explicitly defined copy constructor or assignment operator, the compiler will simply copy the `addr` array for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `operator<` funtion is not right. It does not produce strictly weak ordering. Change it to

```
bool operator<(const Mac &rhs) const {
    return memcmp(addr, rhs.addr, sizeof(Mac)) < 0; // Use < instead of !=
}
```

I would suggest refining it further to

```
bool operator<(const Mac &rhs) const {
    return memcmp(addr, rhs.addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0;
}
```

After all, you are comparing `addr` with `rhs.addr`.

The `operator<` implemented in `MacPair` is also incorrect. You can use

```
bool operator<(const MacPair &rhs) const {
    if ( src_mac != rhs.src_mac )
    {
       return src_mac < rhs.src_mac;
    }
    return dst_mac < rhs.dst_mac;
}
```

The `!=` operator between two `Mac` objects can be implemented using the `<` operator.

```
bool operator!=(const Mac &rhs) const
{
    return (*this < rhs) || (rhs < *this);
}
```

Comment: LOL! What a dumb mistake. Thanks Sahu you are my savior.